# Compare file names in 2 jar files?

Tags: linux, bash, jar

I need to check if all the files in 1 jar exist in another jar. I don't care if the file contents are the same, just the file names. I could open each jar in vim and save those text files that are a list of the file names to compare, but I have a lot of jar sets to compare, so I'd like to fully automate this if possible.

Comment: You're basically asking us to do your work.  Hint: `unzip -l <JAR>` will list you the content of a jar file.

Comment: Please take your time to read how to [formulate better questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [jar file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) is built around the [ZIP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) and usually contains a *manifest file* which is a list of all the files that are included in the jar file. This manifest, if it exists, will have the name `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` and it will be a text file.

So what you want may be achieved by extracting the manifest from each jar pair you want to compare and then looking for differences.

If you have the `jar` command available, you may extract the manifest of a jar file with:

```
jar xf jar1.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

You may also do this with `unzip` if you have it available.

A simple script that would extract the manifests from two jar files and compare them using `diff` would look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

jar xf "$1" META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
mv META-INF/MANIFEST.MF m1.txt
jar xf "$2" META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
mv META-INF/MANIFEST.MF m2.txt

diff m1.txt m2.txt
```

The script takes two parameters, the jar files. If you expect the files in the manifests to be the same but in different order, you may try sorting them first with `sort`. This is only the skeleton of a script. You may want to add things like file cleanup, error checking and so on.

If you only care about the files inside the jar files, you may get a list of them with:

```
jar tf jar1.jar
```

You may also use `unzip` for this: `unzip -l jar1.jar` as suggested in a comment.

Then you may compare the list of files with `diff` in a similar fashion, maybe sorting them with `sort` first.

There is also a related question: [How to read MANIFEST.MF file from JAR using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066063/how-to-read-manifest-mf-file-from-jar-using-bash).

Comment: Play with the results of the `diff`. If I am not mistaken, given two ordered lists of files `l1` and `l2`, `diff l1 l2 | egrep '^<' | wc -l` should give you `0` if `l1` is contained in `l2` and greater than zero otherwise.

Comment: unzip -l, combined with awk, sort, and comm, worked for me. I didn't know about unzip -l, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"I need to check if"...so do you need the script to exit true/false or to output a list of files in first but not second jar? For the latter case this will do:

```
#!/bin/bash
(jar tf "$1";jar tf "$2";jar tf "$2") | \
    sort | uniq -c | perl -pe's/^\s*([23]\s+.*\n|1\s+)//'
```

Store this in `files_just_in_first_jar` and run `chmod +x files_just_in_first_jar` and test with:

```
./files_just_in_first_jar bundle1.jar bundle2.jar
```